# Create a function to determine if a number is even

Tags: python

As the home assignment, I have two code cells. In the first one, I need to write a code, while the second check the written function (it was made by a professor)

[Cell1]

```
def is_even_number(num):
    '''
    Returns True if num is even number, otherwise False
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    num : an integer
    
    Returns
    -------
    True if num is even number, otherwise False
    '''
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    while num:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            return True
        elif num % 2 != 0:
            return False
```

[Cell2]

```
assert_true(is_even_number(2), msg='2 is an even number.')
assert_true(not is_even_number(1), msg='1 is not an even number')
```

As a result of run Cell2, I see the message NameError: name 'assert_true' is not defined

Comment: We can't help you here, we don't know where that function is supposed to be coming from.

Comment: What are `Cell1` and `Cell2`? That looks like something from a particular runtime environment; it's not something defined in Python itself. We can't tell from this where or how `assert_true` is supposed to be defined.

Comment: Wherever `assert_true` *is* defined hasn't been imported to your environment/execution context. Where is it defined? What is confusing about the error message that it is "*not defined*"?

Answer (score 1):

I think it  should be  assertTrue . If it's using the module unittest. Here's the [link](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertTrue)

Comment: I cannot change the professor's cell. Unfortunately :D

Comment: I'm using Jupyter Notebook